# "gyp ERR! build error" - on Mac, after updating

Tags: npm, npm-install

at some point I got an error after each `npm install`. Says something about gyp error but I have no idea how to fix it. That package was working with the old node version. I've tried to remove manually node and install it again but doesn't seem to work (or maybe I'm not doing it properly...)

**Log**:
https://pastebin.com/crzWVwJn

Comment: It looks like `lmdb-store` fails. Either you, or one of your dependencies depends on this package. `lmdb-store` is very old and probably not compatible with the new node version. You should probably upgrade to the new `lmdb` package.

Comment: @Garuno Do you know how can I know which dependency depends on that package? I can see that "lmdb" it's just on package-lock.
Seems that is Parcel.

Comment: I think it should be `npm list` to generate a dependecy tree. From there you can check what depends on the package

Answer (score 0):

Parcel was the problem. I'm not going to use it anymore so I removed it. But first I've tried to update to last version and same problem with the lmdb-store dependency.